# Standalone ServiceStack service for Web & Native Mobile App

Tags: rest, architecture, servicestack

Our architecture consists of several backend (non-ServiceStack) services and applications that send data to our system via ServiceStack service hosted in asp.net - this is currently a standalone ServiceProject project containing our required Services/Repository/DTOs following the structure of all the provided [ServiceStack samples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples).

With our backend complete we're now designing our two front-end requirements consisting of a web application and native mobile application.  For the web application I'd really like to continue leveraging ServiceStack by using the Razor plugin to create the application's layout/views from our existing DTOs, for our mobile app we will only rely on the ServiceStack service for authentication and data - as it is native it's layout/views will come from it's own SDK.

**Can I leave my standalone ServiceStack service as is and:**

1. Create a separate web application project that authenticates
   against our existing standalone ServiceStack service and uses the
   Razor view plugin?
2. Have our native mobile app clients
       authenticate against the same standalone ServiceStack service?

Most of the examples ie. [RazorRockstars](http://razor.servicestack.net/) I've seen have the services embedded in the web project so I'm not sure if this distributed type of setup is supported.  Any guidance or feedback on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible. You can consume the web service from both, web and native mobile application. I worked in a ASP.NET MVC web application which used to make call to Web API service hosted at different server. The Web API service was shared among multiple applications. We were consuming it by making AJAX calls from client.

Something similar to your scenario is done at below link but they are using cloud to host service:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529109/Mobile-2fWebplusClient-2cplusWebplusAPIplusandplus

If you have opportunity to make a web app for mobile instead of native app, then in a single solution both mobile and desktop app can be created. The exemplary solution can be found here:  http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/

Thanks and free free to discuss more in case of further questions.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, were you using authentication with your ajax client calls?

Comment: Most welcome, Yes you are right. While log in, we used to provide a session id for further AJAX calls.